# Replace text with image in a search filter

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've got a search filter set up with a bunch of check boxes and some text.

For example:

Genres:

[] Horror [] Drama

Etc.

For this, I am using a plugin in wordpress where each option has a code like this:

```
<label>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="2[]"> " Horror"
</label>
```

However, I want to change the "Horror" text into an image of, say, a vampire.

Where do I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert an image like this:

```
<form action="WHATEVER ACTION YOU WANT YOUR FORM TO DO (i.e. submit)">
   <input type="image" src="YOUR_IMAGE_HERE.JPG" alt="Horror">
</form>
```

There's more information [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_src).